# How to copy the <ul> along with html into another <ul> in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to copy li items form one ul into another ul along with its html.
So far I am able to copy just the list but I want to copy html inside li items as well as I have different html structure in both list.

**HTML:**

```
<li>
  <a href="#">Cylinder Block MaterialC1228<i class="fa fa-plus-circle pull-right"></i></a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">Cylinder Head MaterialC1229<i class="fa fa-plus-circle pull-right"></i></a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">Engine AspirationC1405<i class="fa fa-plus-circle pull-right"></i></a>
</li>
```

**JS:**

```
function copyFieldItemsintoQueryOrder() {
    $("#ordering-options").empty();
    $("#fields").children().clone().appendTo("#ordering-options");
}
```

How to copy the list items along with html ?

Comment: Have you tried `$("#fields").contents().clone().appendTo("#ordering-options");` or `$("#ordering-options").append($("#fields").html())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the `html` as the other `html`.

```js
$("#ordering-options").html($("#fields").html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>fields</h3>
<ul id="fields">
  <li><a href="#">Cylinder Block MaterialC1228<i class="fa fa-plus-circle pull-right"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Cylinder Head MaterialC1229<i class="fa fa-plus-circle pull-right"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Engine AspirationC1405<i class="fa fa-plus-circle pull-right"></i></a>
  </li>
</ul>

<h3>ordering-options</h3>
<ul id="ordering-options">

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy all `li` items of `ul` then you can try this.

```
<ul id="abc">
    <li><a href="#">Cylinder Block MaterialC1228<i class="fa fa-plus-circle pull-right"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cylinder Head MaterialC1229<i class="fa fa-plus-circle pull-right"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Engine AspirationC1405<i class="fa fa-plus-circle pull-right"></i></a></li>
</ul>

$('#abc').html().appentTo("#ordering-options");
```